# multirow does not work and the text has not located in the middle of the cells

Tags: latex

I have the code below,

```
\begin{table*}[!ht]
    \centering \footnotesize
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{l | l | l | c | c | c | c} \toprule
    Level & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Description}  & Executor & Monitor & Fallbacker & Driving modes \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{Human driver monitors the driving environment}} \\ \midrule
    \makecell[l]{Level 0 \\ No driving \\ automation} & \multicolumn{2}{p{8cm}|}{The full-time performance by the human driver of all aspects of the dynamic driving task, even when "enhanced by warning or intervention systems".} & Human driver & \multirow{3}{*}{Human driver} & \multirow{3}{*}{Human driver} & N/A \\ \cline{1-4} \cline{7-7}
    \makecell[l]{Level 1 \\ Driver assistance} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.5cm}|}{The driving mode-specific execution by a driver assistance system of "either steering or acceleration/deceleration"} & \multirow{2}{3.5cm}{using information about the driving environment and with the expectation that the human driver performs all remaining aspects of the dynamic driving task} & Human driver \& system &  &  & \multirow{2}{*}{some} \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-4}
    \makecell[l]{Level 2 \\ \makecell[l]{Partial \\ driving automation}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.5cm}|}{The driving mode-specific execution by one or more driver assistance systems of both steering and acceleration/deceleration} &  & System &  &  &  \\ \midrule 
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{Automated driving system monitors the driving environment}} \\ \midrule
    \makecell[l]{Level 3 \\ \makecell[l]{Conditional \\ driving automation}} & \multirow{3}{4.5cm}{The driving mode-specific performance by an automated driving system of all aspects of the dynamic driving task} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3.5cm}|}{with the expectation that the human driver will respond appropriately to a request to intervene} & \multirow{3}{*}{System} & \multirow{3}{*}{System} & Human driver & some \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} \cline{6-7}
    \makecell[l]{Level 4 \\ \makecell[l]{High driving \\ automation}} &  & \multicolumn{1}{p{3.5cm}|}{even if a human driver does not respond appropriately to a request to intervene the car can pull over safely by guiding system} &  &  & \multirow{2}{*}{System} & Many \\ \midrule
    \makecell[l]{Level 5 \\ \makecell[l]{Full driving \\ automation}} & & \multicolumn{1}{p{3.5cm}|}{under all roadway and environmental conditions that can be managed by a human driver} &  &  &  & All \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{SAE J3016 levels of driving automation \cite{sae2014automated}.}
    \label{tab:saelevels-wiki}
\end{table*}
```

here is the table
[image]

**The issues are:**

1. It looks like the code `\multirow` does not work.
2. The text has not been put in the middle of the cells. For example, the first and second columns in the third row have not located in the middle (vertical) of cells.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

In addition, here is the original table that I would like to copy, and my packages.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{soul} %ONLY FOR THE DRAFT VERSION, REMOVE AFTERWARDS
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] which we don't have to puzzle together

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `tabularray` package - makes making such tables a piece of cake